# Qt- Delete file

Tags: qt

I need to remove one specific file.
I have tried this:

```
msgBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Ok , tr("Ok"));
msgBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Cancel , tr("Cancel"));

int ret = msgBox.exec();

switch (ret)
{
    case QMessageBox::Ok:
    {
    #ifdef Q_OS_IOS
        QStringList paths = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);
        QString dbFile = paths.first().append("/log.dat");
    #else
        QString dbFile = "log.dat";
    #endif
        QSettings settings(CGlobalZone::m_companyName, CGlobalZone::m_softwareName);
        settings.clear();
        QDir dir;
        dir.remove(dbFile);

        break;

    case QMessageBox::Cancel:
        QTimer::singleShot(1500, this, SLOT(close()));
        break;
}
```

but unfortunately dbFile still exists. How I can remove "dbFile"?

Comment: And? What is the problem?

Comment: Do you work under Windows?

Comment: @Greenflow yes, I'm working on Windows version

Comment: See comment on Farzan Njr's answer. Either the path is wrong, or your file is still opened. You cannot delete open files under Windows.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use

```
    QFile file (dbFile);
    file.remove();
```

instead of

```
  QDir dir;
   dir.remove(dbFile);
```

Comment: Does not matter. dir.remove should work. Unless the path is wrong, or he is working under Windows and the file is still open.

Comment: I tried this with `QFileInfo`, hoping they would have a universal `remove()`, but no dice :(

Answer (score 24):

An even shorter solution to remove a file in Qt might be:

```
QFile::remove(dbFile);
```